# No muestra ventana de dialogo. En android mayor a 6

Tags: android

Estoy realizando una aplicacion donde pueda guardaren bd online. tengo un celular con android 4.4.2 en el cual realizo todas las pruebas. pero al momento de instalarlo en una android con version 8.1.0 muestra los mensajes de dialogo si quiero dar persimos a la camara, almacenamiento interno asta ahi todo bien. en las 2 ultimas imageneas de abajo muestro que estan los permisos.

al presionar la imagen de contacto en el cel con  android 8.1 no muestra la venta de dialogo para elegir si quiero tomar una foto o buscarla de galeria.

talvez me puedan indicar en que estoy fallando con el codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
package com.example.administrador.contactosonline.Fragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.administrador.contactosonline.R;
import com.example.administrador.contactosonline.VolleySingleton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission_group.CAMERA;


public class AgregarContactosFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static final String TAG=AgregarContactosFragment.class.getSimpleName();


    TextView txtcontacto,txttelef1,txtrutaimagen;
    ImageView img_contacto;
    Button btnRegContacto;
    ImageButton btn_img_contacto;


    private final int MIS_PERMISOS=100;
    private final int COD_SELECCIONA=10;
    private final int COD_FOTO=20;

    //DIRECTORIP PRINCIPAL
    private static final String CARPTE_PRINCIPAL="misImagenesApp";
    //CARPETA DONDE SE GUARDAN LAS FOTOS
    private static final String CARMPETA_IMAGEN= "imagenes";
    //RUTA CARPETA DIRECTORIOS
    private static final String DIRECTORIO_IMAGEN=CARPTE_PRINCIPAL + CARMPETA_IMAGEN;
    //ALMACENA LA RUTA DE LA IMAGEN
    private String path;
    File fileImagen;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    TextView prefUsuario;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    StringRequest stringRequest;


    public AgregarContactosFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static AgregarContactosFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AgregarContactosFragment fragment = new AgregarContactosFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agregar_contactos, container, false);

        txtcontacto= vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_nomb_contacto_id);
        txttelef1=vista.findViewById(R.id.txt_telf1_contacto_id);

        img_contacto=vista.findViewById(R.id.img_foto_contacto);
        btnRegContacto=vista.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarContacto);
        prefUsuario=vista.findViewById(R.id.prefUsuario);


        //btn registrar el contacto
        btnRegContacto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RegistrarContactoWS();
               
            }
        });

        //buscar la imagen del contacto
        img_contacto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mostrarDialogOpciones();
               
            }
        });


        //Permisos
        if(solicitaPermisosVersionesSuperiores()){
            img_contacto.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            img_contacto.setEnabled(false);
        }

        SharedPreferences p = getContext().getSharedPreferences("preferencia", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefUsuario.setText(p.getString("txtUsuario","Iniciar Sesion"));

        return vista;
    }

    public void RegistrarContactoWS() {
        String url="http://192.168.1.3/bd/registrarContacto.php?";
        url=url.replace(" ","%20");


        stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("estado")){
                    Log.i(TAG+" :..RESPUESTA..: ",""+response);
                }else{
                    Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+response);
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha podido conectar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+error);
                    }
                })
        {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                String nombre=txtcontacto.getText().toString();
                String telf1=txttelef1.getText().toString();
                String imagen=convertirImgString(bitmap);
                String trusuario=prefUsuario.getText().toString();

                Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("nombre",nombre);
                parametros.put("telf1",telf1);
                parametros.put("imagen",imagen);
                parametros.put("trusuario",trusuario);

                return parametros;
            }
        };
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
    private String convertirImgString(Bitmap bitmap) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream array=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,array);
        byte[] imagenByte=array.toByteArray();
        String imagenString= Base64.encodeToString(imagenByte,Base64.DEFAULT);

        return imagenString;
    }

    //METODO CARGAR GALERIA TOMAR FOTO
    private void mostrarDialogOpciones() {
        final CharSequence[] opciones={"Tomar Foto","Galeria","Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Elige una Opción");
        builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (opciones[i].equals("Tomar Foto")){
                    abriCamara();
                }else{
                    if (opciones[i].equals("Galeria")){
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.setType("image/");
                        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione"),COD_SELECCIONA);
                    }else{
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void abriCamara() {
        File miFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),DIRECTORIO_IMAGEN);
        boolean isCreada=miFile.exists();

        if(isCreada==false){
            isCreada=miFile.mkdirs();
        }

        if(isCreada==true){
            Long consecutivo= System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
            String nombre=consecutivo.toString()+".jpg";

            path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+DIRECTORIO_IMAGEN
                    +File.separator+nombre;//indicamos la ruta de almacenamiento

            fileImagen=new File(path);

            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(fileImagen));

            ////
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            {
                String authorities=getContext().getPackageName()+".provider";
                Uri imageUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),authorities,fileImagen);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            }else
            {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fileImagen));
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent,COD_FOTO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode){
            case COD_SELECCIONA:
                Uri miPath=data.getData();
                img_contacto.setImageURI(miPath);


                try {
                    bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(),miPath);
                   img_contacto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case COD_FOTO:
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{path}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("Path",""+path);
                            }
                        });

                bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                img_contacto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                break;
        }
        bitmap=redimensionarImagen(bitmap,600,800);
    }

    private Bitmap redimensionarImagen(Bitmap bitmap, float anchoNuevo, float altoNuevo) {

        int ancho=bitmap.getWidth();
        int alto=bitmap.getHeight();

        if(ancho>anchoNuevo || alto>altoNuevo){
            float escalaAncho=anchoNuevo/ancho;
            float escalaAlto= altoNuevo/alto;

            Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(escalaAncho,escalaAlto);

            return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,ancho,alto,matrix,false);

        }else{
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
    //FIN METODO CARGAR GALERIA TOMAR FOTO
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////



    // **********************PERMISOS******************** //

    //PERMISOS
    private boolean solicitaPermisosVersionesSuperiores() {
        //validamos si estamos en android menor a 6 para no buscar los permisos
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            return true;
        }

        //validamos si los permisos ya fueron aceptados
        if((getContext().checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&& getContext().checkSelfPermission(CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        }

        if ((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)||(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)))){
            cargarDialogoRecomendacion();
        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MIS_PERMISOS);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode==MIS_PERMISOS){
            if(grantResults.length==2 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){//el dos representa los 2 permisos
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Permisos aceptados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                img_contacto.setEnabled(true);//se vincula el evento a la imagen
             
            }
        }else{
            solicitarPermisosManual();
        }
    }

    private void solicitarPermisosManual() {
        final CharSequence[] opciones={"si","no"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertOpciones=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());//estamos en fragment
        alertOpciones.setTitle("¿Desea configurar los permisos de forma manual?");
        alertOpciones.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (opciones[i].equals("si")){
                    Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri=Uri.fromParts("package",getContext().getPackageName(),null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Los permisos no fueron aceptados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        alertOpciones.show();
    }

    private void cargarDialogoRecomendacion() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        dialogo.setTitle("Permisos Desactivados");
        dialogo.setMessage("Debe aceptar los permisos para el correcto funcionamiento de la App");

        dialogo.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,CAMERA},100);
            }
        });
        dialogo.show();
    }

///////////////FIN PERMISOS


  


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has añadido los permisos en el manifest? Igual es por eso.

Comment: Cual es el error que se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: si claro los permisos los tengo en el manifest **Miquel** y no me muestra ningun error **Elenasys**. como les habia dicho tengo un cel con la version  4.4.2. y trabaja todo bien me consede los permisos muestra las ventanas de dialogo. realice la instalacion en cel android version 8.1.0. me muestra el mensaje si quiero darle permisos para utilizar la camara y guardar o buscar en el almacenamiento. al tocar la imagen de la foto como se muestra en la 1era imagen. no carga la ventana de dialogo para seleccionar siqiero tomar una foto o buscarla.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que aunque requieras permisos manualmente para dispositivos con Android M o superior es importante definas los permisos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Ahora veo que tu método para verificar permisos es correcto

```
private boolean solicitaPermisosVersionesSuperiores() {
        //validamos si estamos en android menor a 6 para no buscar los permisos
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            return true;
        }

        //validamos si los permisos ya fueron aceptados
        if((getContext().checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&& getContext().checkSelfPermission(CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        }

        if ((shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)||(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA)))){
            cargarDialogoRecomendacion();
        }else{
            requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, MIS_PERMISOS);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Pero el import debe ser del permiso paea la camara y no del grupo de permisos:

```
//import static android.Manifest.permission_group.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
```

Comment: Saludos Elanasys. seguire tus indicaciones por ahora are las preubas y te comento. Saludos

Comment: @novatophp2014 excelente comenta los resultados obtenidos.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta tu comentario lo dejamos de esta manera _import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;_ al momento de ejecutar la app por 1era vez  pedi los permisos **Allow Contactos Online to accesss photos,media and files on your devices?** luego toco la imagen del usuario para que me muestre la ventana de dialogo Pero no la muestra y esto es loq obtenemos_D/ViewRootImpl@9d048bd[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0 D/ViewRootImpl@9d048bd[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1_